# Different DNS resolution for multiple IPs

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, dns-hosting

Greeting's, I am trying to configure different DNS resolutions for:

1. **maniarfamily.com** -- I want maniarfamily.com (or www.maniarfamily.com / https://www.maniarfamily.com) to point to Wix (**23.236.62.147**).
2. **cloud.maniarfamily.com** -- I want this to point to a different IP **116.72.137.140**

I have purchased the domain from GoDaddy and I am using GoDaddy's nameservers.

Following are the records I have made:

**for maniarfamily.com:**

1. "A" record with **@** pointing to **23.236.62.147**
2. "CNAME" record with **www.maniarfamily.com** pointing to **www37.wixdns.net**
3. "CNAME" record with **www** pointing to **www38.wixdns.net**
4. "NS" record with **maniarfamily.com** pointing to **ns10.wixdns.net**
5. "NS" record with **maniarfamily.com** pointing to **ns11.wixdns.net**

**for cloud.maniarfamily.com:**

1. "A" record with **cloud.maniarfamily.com** pointing to **116.72.137.140.**
2. "A" record with **www.cloud.maniarfamily.com** pointing to **116.72.137.140.**
3. "CNAME" record with **cloud** pointing to **cloud.maniarfamily.com**
4. "CNAME" record with **cloud** pointing to **cloud.maniarfamily.com**

There are default entries by GoDaddy of nameservers (NS)

NS @ ns15.domaincontrol.com
NS @ ns16.domaincontrol.com

I am obviously doing it horribly wrong. As earlier cloud.maniarfamily.com used to correctly resolve to 116.72.137.140.

**However current nslookup output for cloud.maniarfamily.com:**

```
nslookup cloud.maniarfamily.com 8.8.8.8
    Server:  dns.google
    Address:  8.8.8.8
    dns.google can't find cloud.maniarfamily.com: Server failed
```

**However current nslookup output for maniarfamily.com:** <--- *This is as required.*

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    maniarfamily.com
Address:  23.236.62.147
```

Comment: you don't need the redundant cname records  you are also probably better off asking over on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

The two NS records you added are wrong. These must not be changed without also changing where your DNS is hosted, but you did not do that. You chose to host your DNS at GoDaddy, not at Wix. They must be changed back to ns15.domaincontrol.com. and ns16.domaincontrol.com.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have removed NS records of WIX. Only two uneditable NS records of GoDaddy remain:  NS @ ns15.domaincontrol.com  and NS @ ns15.domaincontrol.com

Comment: @ParthManiar OK, now just wait for the TTL to expire. You probably should also put the A record for @, as you seem to have deleted it.

Comment: I would also like to know why typing maniarfamily.com gives error **ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED** and typing www.maniarfamily.com shows the webpage? (meaning DNS resolution is successful).

Comment: It still isn't working. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Following helped me:

Clear previous records

After that add

```
Type A, name: @, Value: 23.236.62.147

Type Cname, name: www, Value: @

Type A, name: cloud, Value: 116.72.137.140
```